# Make GridVew Item Fill the Empty Space In FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a grid item that automatically fill the container.

[image]

What I want is like this. I use `childAspectRatio` for this one, but if I decrease the item number, it cannot fill up the container.

[image]

This is my code for the grid

```
Column (
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                 color: Colors.grey,
                  height: 150,
                  child: _gridView ()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
  )

  Widget _gridView () {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 3,
        children: List.generate(6, (index) {
          return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SizedBox(
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child: null,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("Cliked");
                    },)
              ));
        })
    );
  }
```

Some reference said I should use `Expanded`, but I still confused where to put it.

Comment: what blank space are you talking about?

Comment: @EhsanAskari I mean I want to fill the container. I will give the intended result to make it more clear.

Comment: you want it to scroll horizontally?

Comment: @EhsanAskari yes

Comment: if it is horizontally scrollable why do you want it to fill the container?

Comment: If the item count below 7, I want it to fill the container (to make it neat) because I can only scroll it when the item is more than 7.

Comment: the gridview is horizontally scrollable which means it has infinite space on the horizontal axis, and you can not set size on it

Answer (score -1):

set the `childAspectRatio` dynamic based on device width.

```
Widget _gridView(BuildContext context) {
    int length = 8;
    double height = 150;
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
      crossAxisSpacing: 3,
      childAspectRatio: length < 7
          ? (height / 2) /
              (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / ((length + 1) ~/ 2))
          : 2 / 3,
      children: List.generate(
        length,
        (index) {
          return Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                child: SizedBox(),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Cliked");
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked it on dartpad? Kindly put output.

Answer (score -1):

Check what I have changed:

```
 Widget _gridView (BuildContext context) {
    double cardWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6;
    double cardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3;
   
    return GridView.count(
         crossAxisCount: 2,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 3,
        childAspectRatio: cardWidth / cardHeight,
        children: List.generate(6, (index) {
          return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SizedBox(
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child: null,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("Cliked");
                    },)
              ));
        })
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Dont forget to pass context inside this method.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, But I have a question, when I change the item count to 4, its still not displaying correctly (what i mean is, it the space become so wide). So do we need to change the ratio depends on the item in the grid?